# Getting the following error ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row 01427. 00000 - "single-row subquery returns more than one row"

Tags: sql, oracle

I am getting the following error:

I want to get a column value from the first query and pass that value to the next query.

ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"

---

with the following query:

```
 with

deal_XX AS(

SELECT distinct idh.vendor supplier
                  ,idh.deal_id
                  ,mff_report.mff_merch_sql.get_sup_name(idh.vendor) sup_name


              FROM im_doc_head idh
                  ,mff_report.stage_complex_deal_head_hist scdhh
                  ,im_complex_deal_detail icdd
                  ,mff_report.v_loc vl
                  ,item_master im
                                  ,item_master im_parent
             WHERE (   (    idh.type IN ('DEBMEC','CRDMEC') --Debit and Credit Memos in APPROVED or POSTED
                        AND idh.status IN ('APPRVE','POSTED'))
                    OR (    idh.type = 'CRDNRC'             --Credit Note Requests in APPROVED or MATCHED
                        AND idh.status IN ('APPRVE','MTCH')))
               AND idh.deal_type = 'C'
               AND NVL(:PM_supplier,idh.vendor) = idh.vendor

               AND idh.deal_id = scdhh.deal_id (+)
               AND SUBSTR(idh.ext_doc_id,(INSTR(idh.ext_doc_id,'-',1) + 1),INSTR(idh.ext_doc_id,'-',1,2) - (INSTR(idh.ext_doc_id,'-',1) + 1)) = scdhh.deal_detail_id (+)
               AND idh.doc_date = scdhh.end_invoice_date (+)
               AND idh.doc_id = icdd.doc_id
               AND icdd.location = vl.loc
               AND icdd.item = im.item
                               AND im.item_parent = im_parent.item (+)
               AND (   :PM_supplier IS NOT NULL
                    OR :PM_doc_date_from IS NOT NULL
                    OR :PM_doc_date_to IS NOT NULL
                    OR :PM_approval_date_from IS NOT NULL
                    OR :PM_approval_date_to IS NOT NULL
                    OR :PM_ext_doc_id IS NOT NULL
                    OR :PM_batch_mode = 'Y')
                    )  

  select distinct  ship.order_no    , (select deal_id from deal_XX) hhhh
  from ordloc_discount od
     ,shipment ship
     ,mff_report.stage_complex_deal_head_hist scdhh  
    where od.deal_ID = (select deal_id from deal_XX) 

    and od.deal_id = scdhh.deal_id 
    and ship.status_code = 'R'
    and od.order_no = ship.order_no
    and ship.receive_date BETWEEN
        to_date(scdhh.start_invoice_date , 'YYYY-MM-DD" "HH24:MI:SS')
         AND
         to_date(scdhh.end_invoice_date , 'YYYY-MM-DD" "HH24:MI:SS') ;
```

Comment: Well, how many rows does `select deal_id from deal_XX` return when run on its own? Don’t you want to join to that CTE, rather than use subqueries?

Comment: About 180 Order no for the one deal is what I am expecting.

Answer (score 0):

If you run Q1:`select deal_id from deal_XX` then you probably get more than one row. Therefore, there are two issues:

1. Having `select *, (subselect) from tableX` then the subselect has to return always just one value for each row of the `tableX`. Since you have Q1 as a subselect, your query fails.
2. The same issue is when you have `select * from tableX X where X.y = (subselect)`. Again, query processor expects you to provide a subselect returning just one value for each row  of `TableX` and you have Q1 returning many rows.

The solutions depend on what you are trying to achieve. The second issue could be possibly fixed using `od.deal_ID IN (select deal_id from deal_XX)` meaning that you want rows where deal_id can be found in the list of `deal_id`s returned by `deal_XX`.